# Excel: select the last number or numbers from a cell

Tags: excel

Given the following examples,

```
16A6
ECCB15
```

I would only like to extract the last number or numbers from the string value. So the end result that I'm looking for is:

```
6
15
```

I've been trying to find a way, but can't seem to find the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=--RIGHT(A2,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"E",";"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))))))
```

or this (avoid using **INDIRECT**):

```
=--RIGHT(A2,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"E",";"),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A2)))))))
```

Replace `A2` in the above formula to suit your case.

[image: Example]

Here are the data for testing:

```
| String    |
|-----------|
| 16A6      |
| ECCB15    |
| BATT5A6   |
| 16        |
| A1B2C3E0  |
| 16E       |
| TEST00004 |
```

> I have an even shorter version: `--RIGHT(A2,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"E",";"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))))))`
>
> The difference is the use of **SUBSTITUTE** in my final formula. I used **SUBSTITUTE** to replace letter **E** with a symbol because in the fifth string in the above list, the **RIGHT** function in my formula will return the following: `{"0";"E0";"3E0";"C3E0";"2C3E0";"B2C3E0";"1B2C3E0";"A1B2C3E0"}` where the third string `3E0` will return `TRUE` by **ISNUMBER** function, and this will result in an incorrect answer. Therefore I need to get rid of letter **E** first.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Use thisformula:

```
=MID(A1,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($Z$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))/(NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),1)))),1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: The formula returns the correct value for the first cell, but I'm getting ECCB15 on the second result. I've tried the formula on a column and the result is not consistent.

Comment: `Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.` It works just fine - make sure you hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` when you enter the formula initially.

Comment: did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter when exiting edit mode, did Excel put the `{}` around the formula @LucasC922

Comment: OK. So i cannot drag the formula down the column?

Comment: Yes you can.  Put the formula in the first cell.  Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then drag down. @LucasC922

Comment: I tried it with "BATT5A6", hoping the formula will return 6. Instead I'm getting "T5A6." Any suggestion, please?

Comment: From dragging down, by the way.